# Show polygons within polygons on a multi-layered shapefile map in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I want to use multiple layers of shapefiles that sit on top of each other. I have three depth levels of bathymetry maps (i.e. 200m, 1000m and 2000m). There are some "holes" (*Not a white land polygon) in the polygons as you can see in a map below that I generated in QGIS (i.e. there are 2000m depth polygons within 200m one):

[image: Bathymetry map created by QGIS]

And this is what I made in ggplot2 using the same shapefiles:
[image: Bathymetry map created by ggplot2]

Polygons within polygons are not shown on the ggplot map. How can I get around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

R-scripts used for the map are:

```
Thailand <- readShapePoly("Thailand.shp")
Thailand2 <- fortify(Thailand)
Bthy_200m <- readShapePoly("ne_10m_bathymetry_K_200.shp")
Bthy_1000m <- readShapePoly("ne_10m_bathymetry_all/ne_10m_bathymetry_J_1000.shp")
Bthy_2000m <- readShapePoly("ne_10m_bathymetry_all/ne_10m_bathymetry_I_2000.shp")

Bthy_200m_crop <- crop(Bthy_200m, extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534))
Bthy_1000m_crop <- crop(Bthy_1000m, extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534))
Bthy_2000m_crop <- crop(Bthy_2000m, extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534))

Bthy_200m_crop2<- fortify(Bthy_200m_crop)
Bthy_1000m_crop2<- fortify(Bthy_1000m_crop)
Bthy_2000m_crop2<- fortify(Bthy_2000m_crop)

ggplot()+geom_polygon(data = Bthy_200m_crop2, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill="#52958b", na.rm =TRUE)+geom_polygon(data = Bthy_1000m_crop2, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill="#128277", na.rm =TRUE)+geom_polygon(data = Bthy_2000m_crop2, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill="#004D47", na.rm =TRUE)+geom_polygon(data = est_contour, aes(long, lat, group = group), fill="#99CCCC")+  geom_path(data = est_contour, aes(long, lat, group = group), color = "black")+theme_bw()+theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#5EA8A7"))+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

The shapefiles are found here: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-bathymetry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I downloaded some of the files mentioned. To see polygons within polygons, I'd suggest using geom_sf. Here's some code as well as a picture of the output to make sure it's what you needed. Here's the code to generate this with geom_sf. Note, I did not use thailand as I couldn't find the shapefile nor did i use the estuary shapefile  but you should be able to apply this code to the plot

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

Bthy_200m <- read_sf("ne_10m_bathymetry_K_200.shp")
Bthy_1000m <- read_sf("ne_10m_bathymetry_J_1000.shp")
Bthy_2000m <- read_sf("ne_10m_bathymetry_I_2000.shp")


Bthy_200m_crop <- st_intersection(Bthy_200m,st_set_crs(st_as_sf(as(extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534),"SpatialPolygons")), st_crs(Bthy_200m)))
Bthy_1000m_crop <- st_intersection(Bthy_1000m, st_set_crs(st_as_sf(as(extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534),"SpatialPolygons")), st_crs(Bthy_1000m)))
Bthy_2000m_crop <- st_intersection(Bthy_2000m, st_set_crs(st_as_sf(as(extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534),"SpatialPolygons")), st_crs(Bthy_2000m)))


Bthy_200m_crop2<- fortify(Bthy_200m_crop)
Bthy_1000m_crop2<- fortify(Bthy_1000m_crop)
Bthy_2000m_crop2<- fortify(Bthy_2000m_crop)
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = Bthy_200m_crop2,fill = "#52958b",na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_sf(data = Bthy_1000m_crop2, fill = "#128277",na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_sf(data = Bthy_2000m_crop2, fill="#004D47", na.rm =TRUE)+
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(Bthy_1000m_crop2), datum = NA)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#5EA8A7"))+ 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I get errors when I type:

> Bthy_200m_crop <- st_intersection(Bthy_200m,st_set_crs(st_as_sf(as(extent(84.11236, 108.4594, -4.046979, 24.09534),"SpatialPolygons")), st_crs(Bthy_200m)))
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") : 
  no applicable method for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"

What did I do wrong?